# How to pass paragraph id from layout builder to view?

Tags: views, 9, paragraphs, layout-builder

I have asked this question before but in a different, more convoluted context. This is a simpler example.

I have a paragraph type which I use Layout Builder to define it's layout. In that layout I have a View (paragraph) used to display content from that paragraph. If I add a contextual filter for Paragraph ID to my View and in Views preview I enter a PID, the View displays the correct results. But there is no way I can see to pass the PID from my layout to the view.

There is a Views option to set Block settings and enable Contextual filter which then shows up when I configure the block in LB. But this will not accept a token like [paragraph:id]; although technically it shouldn't need this as the View should know the context of where it is placed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `There is a Views option to set Block settings and enable Contextual filter which then shows up when I configure the block in LB` where? I don't see it. Perhaps this is coming from a contrib module that I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

- In this case, don't create a paragraph View

[image]

- Instead, create a content View

[image]

- Then under Advanced, add relationship to your node's paragraph field.
- In Fields, add your paragraph fields.
- Now you can add context of ID and grab from URL.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have done a few views like that; but for this one there are reasons it is preferred to do this as a Paragraphs view and I am trying to understand how its possible to pass the paragraph ID, or if not, why that wouldn't be possible. As it turns out I have "hacked this in" by setting pid as a static var during paragraph_load and then wrote a new argument handler for PID which pulls this value - but can't help feeling this should be there naturally.

Comment: Another hacky way, to be dynamic instead or hard coded, would be to add the paragraph ID as a field in the content view, and then use [Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) and to insert the paragraph view in your content view which will pass the paragraph ID as contextual.

Comment: `if not, why that wouldn't be possible` @liquidcms Coding wise, anything is possible, I think such feature just needs to be built. However, it probably hasn't been built because its not really needed. Most people don't use Views to display a single paragraph in LB. What most people do is **1)** create a "view mode" (admin/structure/display-modes/view) **2)** Enable view mode in paragraph manage display. **3)** In LB insert the paragraph directly and select the "view mode" they created in step1 for the configuration setting. **4)** Theme the "view mode" by creating a template file (twig) & CSS.

Comment: PS:  step 1 and 2 isn't mandatory. You could use "default" as your view mode if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method: in the LB I remove all the fields and keep only the "title" field (for example) and I use "view" as a formatter of the field.

Then choose the view you created previously and as "View Arguments" I select "Entity ID".

I use this method when I need to create views that have "logic" behind that I can edit faster than creating a template / twig.

We use a lot of contrib modules and I don't know if this possibility comes from the core or from a module.

I use this method on D9.